# simple regex invert inbetween characters

Tags: regex

If I have code :

```
ex(?!a)
```

will match exi exu exo etc... but not exa.

But why when I used this code :

```
ex(?!a)plasma
```

It won't match exiplasma or exoplasma? Why is it ?

I want to match any **ex[X]plasma** format where **[X]** is any character except 'a'. What's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's see what you are doing with `ex(?!a)`. You are saying.

> Match `ex` literally and look ahead if `a` is absent.

With `ex(?!a)plasma` you are saying.

> Match `ex` literally and look ahead if `a` is absent. If it's absent then match `plasma`.

In either of them you haven't mentioned to match anything after `ex`. To match any alphabet after `ex` you will have to use character class `[a-z]` after is.

Try using this regex: `ex(?!a)[a-z]plasma`

This will match `exiplasma` or `exoplasma` but **not** `exaplasma`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT5sJ8/3)**

Answer (score 2):

Based on following documentation from http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html:

> "lookaround", are zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors explained earlier in this tutorial. The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match.

They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not. If you want to match any character except an special one you can use a negated character class:

```
ex[^a]plasma
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
ex(?!a).plasma
```

where dot matches any character after negative lookahead.

Or simply:

```
ex[^a]plasma
```

Where `[^a]` matches any character other than `a`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH3zL1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Because a zero-width assertion does not move the position of the regex engine (hence the name).

You mean

```
ex(?!a).plasma
```

Note the dot. This moves the position forward by one character, matching whatever "is not an `a`".

In the same way, `ex(?!a)` matches the `"ex"` in `"exo"`, it does not match the entire `"exo"`.